# How to Declare Global Array Variable in SAS?

Tags: arrays, sas, global-variables, sas-macro

I'm new to SAS and spinning my wheels. The SAS documentation and other Google searches have not helped me figure this out. How can I declare a global array variable that I can use in various procedures to loop through the contents?

Here is what I've tried:

```
%let fileArray = array{*} $32 file1-file4  ('ce_abcdef_filedetail1' 'ce_abcdef_filedetail2' 'ce_abcdef_filedetail3' 'ce_abcdef_filedetail4' );

/* Loop through each file and run the macro*/
do i = 1 to dim(fileArray);
     %analyze_file(FILENAME=&fileArray[i], PATH=&path, OUTPUT=&output)
end;
```

I need it to pass the filename that I specify in the global array.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: SAS does not natively support arrays in macro variables.  There are many ways of doing what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: What are you trying to do in analyze_file? Depending on what you're doing there may be easier ways overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is basically to use a data driven programming approach to drive your macros.  Good for you!  However, you can't do it directly the way you are trying to.  While you could use a macro array the way Yukclam9 mentions, there's an easier way.

SAS doesn't use arrays the way `r` uses vectors or matrices: SAS uses datasets, though, and you can do a lot of the same things.

Put your filenames into a dataset - perhaps they're already there, in an excel file or something?  Let's put it here in datalines, in case they're not.

```
data filenames;
  input filename :$32.;
  datalines;
ce_abcdef_filedetail1
ce_abcdef_filedetail2 
ce_abcdef_filedetail3 
ce_abcdef_filedetail4
;;;;
run;
```

Now, you want to get them into a macro call. Sweet, we have a lot of ways of doing that.  This is the quickest.

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%analyze_file(FILENAME=',filename,", PATH=&path, OUTPUT=&output)")
    into :mcalllist separated by ' '
    from filenames;
quit;
```

CATS just concatenates and strips spaces.  I leave `&path` and `&output` alone as it looks like they're global macro variables - of course if they're also variable, you could include them the same way.

Now `&mcalllist` is a global macro variable that stores your four macro calls (or however many were in that dataset, one per row)!  You just execute

```
&mcalllist
```

and presto, it calls your macro.  You can also use `call execute` or construct a file and `%include` it to do much the same thing, with some different limitations.  (This one has a maximum of 65k characters or so, for example.)

Comment: I'll play with this and the suggestion by yukclam to see if I can get either method to work. I'm floored that SAS doesn't have an easier way to do this. Thanks

Comment: This is a very easy way to do this, in my opinion - particularly for the common use case [ie, I have a spreadsheet listing all of the stores in my company, I want to run a report for each of them] - import spreadsheet and run one line of code.  SAS doesn't make it particularly easy to do this using 'global variables', because that's not how SAS works - and even languages like R you shouldn't do it that way, really.  While SAS is not an OOP language, it has a lot of the concepts - and a 'dataset' is your 'object'.

Comment: Joe- I accepted your answer - it seems to work despite giving me an error message: ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

I don't think it likes how I am calling &mcalllist:

data _null_;
 call execute(&mcalllist);
run;

Comment: You don't call execute anything: you just put `&mcalllist` as a line in your program, by itself.  It will be replaced by what was put in it.  You can type that (and nothing else) on the line immediately following the `quit;`, or anywhere later than that.

Comment: @Joe
May i know what is the purpose of the comma within the quotes for (FILENAME=',filename," ) ? thank you

Comment: The commas have nothing to do with the filename, the commas are for separating the parameters of the cats function. You concatenate your first string with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Check this informative article: [Macro Array Statement](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/040-31.pdf)

What you could do would be to create the array by

```
%array ( younameit, values = 'ce_abcdef_filedetail1' 'ce_abcdef_filedetail2' ...)
```

note that the term "values" is fixed and values after the "=" is up to you

and do it with `%do_over`

```
%macro read_file(fileArray);
  %analyze_file(FILENAME=&fileArray, PATH=&path, OUTPUT=&output)
  %end;
%mend read_file;

%do_over(younameit, macro=read_file)
```

The result would trigger macro read_file('ce_abcdef_filedetail1' ), read_file('ce_abcdef_filedetail2') and the remained respectively. I would also suggest you to put the quote ( double quote to trigger macro) into the statement but not with the macro variable.

Comment: Good answer, but you definitely need to mention the fact that a macro array is not a true array (and not a standard feature of the language).  The OP clearly misunderstands that.

Comment: Also - I think you misunderstand how `%do_over` works here.  Certainly you can't use `dim` that way - it is a data step function.  Please read the paper you linked to and fix that section.